# How can I find out the minimum version of Java that is safe to use across a large number of Android phones?

Tags: java, android

I recently found out at work we're limiting our Java target to 1.1, because there are supposedly still Android phones that only support up to that version.  I've been trying to Google which versions of Java are installed on the different version of Android (unless they do get updated, then what is the minimum version that's included?), and have had no such luck in my search.

So, I'm trying to find out what is realistically the best minimum target for Java on Android.  Know of any good sources detailing the versions of Java used across Android devices?

[Edit]
For clarification, we're using the Java SDK to build a jar, then packaging it into the apk.  So I do need to know a specific Java SDK target, not the Android API level.

Comment: I've used JDK 1.6 and it's worked on Android 1.5... who told you about limiting to java 1.1? Shoot them. :) Actually maybe they got confused with J2ME.

Comment: Haha.  We have an Android checklist that ALL games produced by the company must follow.  I'm assuming this is one of those things that everyone blindly follows, without questioning why we're doing it, until now.  I'm hoping to get the ball rolling, if I can find something official to show them.

Comment: I would like to note it turns out there is a good reason for doing this, so they can port the java code to MIDP20 devices.  So we're still going to be stuck on Java 1.1.

Comment: Note test you Can retroweave code to older versions.  Generics is so helpful in making robust programs that it is worth using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: It's nowadays Java 7 without try-with-resource and without some newer methods & classes. Your IDE will complain if you use something you shouldn't.

The Android tools know Java 7 and are capable of transforming it into Android bytecode that runs on old devices.

One can also use the full set of Java 7 features (i.e. including try-with-resources) for apps targeting Android 4.4 and up.

---

[Downloading and Building](http://source.android.com/source/building.html) Android itself requires

> JDK 6 if you wish to build Gingerbread or newer; JDK 5 for Froyo or older.

Building older versions with JDK 6 works in my experience since the class format generated by the Java compiler is still compatible with the class format of JDK 5.

The same applies to Apps. Android's internal Java implementation is not the same as the JDK so it has no comparable version numbers. But for example `String#isEmpty()` that was added in [JDK 6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty%28%29) says `Added in API level 9` in [Android's documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty%28%29) which is exactly the version after aforementioned Froyo.

Eclipse / Android Lint will also mark usage of those methods as error if your App has a lower minimum version than 9.

Using JDK 6 to build any app should work perfectly fine. Your code must not use core Java methods that did not exist on older Android versions just like any other method in the Android framework. It is also no problem to use `@Override` annotations for implemented interfaces since that annotation is not included in the `.class` file (see [`RetentionPolicy.SOURCE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/RetentionPolicy.html#SOURCE)).

What actually matters in the end is that Android's dex compiler that turns all the `.class` files into an Android `.dex` file actually understands the class format and can produce a valid dex file. The dex format is the one has to be understood by whatever old Android phone you have and I'd assume that the dex compiler makes sure that it produces a valid format for any version of Android. (Here is AFAIK the problem with JDK 7 since the class format has changed)

I'd suggest that you use Java 6 as compile target to build any of your apps. That results in the most recent version of `.class` file that the dex compiler understands. Older versions do work but you might get warnings like the following

```
[dx] warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
[dx] (com.bubblesoft.org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl$1) that doesn't come with an
[dx] associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
[dx] compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
[dx] solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
[dx] and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
[dx] this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
[dx] indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
```

Answer (score 3):

You can support all major versions of Android (2.1 and above, possibly even lower) with Java 1.6.

Infact, as long as you compile with anything but 1.7 you'll be fine, though compiling with 1.5 and below gives a bunch of errors with `@Override` annotations. 1.6 is your safest bet. I've used it in all my apps so far, and haven't found a single device that was incompatible because of my Java version.

Comment: Do you have any sources?  I have to try to convince an entire company it's safe to do so.  They're not going to easily budge.

Comment: @leetNightshade Not in any official documentation, but the Wikipedia page [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Java_and_Android_API) can tell you that Android does not follow official Java SE releases, and instead just uses the language as a tool, not a platform (Android is based on Dalvik VM, not the Java VM like Java SE). As WarrenFaith's answer points out, the Java you see around you is different from the one in Android.

Comment: @leetNightshade http://source.android.com/source/building.html for example says that Android itself has to be built with java 5 or 6. It's not really related to what version of Java is used internally in Android but it might help convice

Comment: I would gladly accept an answer that includes the link provided by @zapl, as that fully answers what I was looking for.  Thank you @zapl!

Comment: @zapl Feel free to add an answer of your own!

Answer (score 2):

First don't confuse Java with Android. The Java-RE and the Android system itself are different.

If you talk about Android versions, you should support API level 8 at a minimum and target API level 17. That should give your access to 90% and more of all Android devices.

The rest Raghav already wrote.

For Java as a compiler itself: You can use JavaSDK 7 without any issue but you shouldn't use a compile setting above 1.6. Using 1.1 is way outdated!

Comment: I'm not confusing Java with Android.  I'm not concerned with the Android API target, but the Java SDK target.  Though, doesn't API level 9 support more than 90% by now?

Comment: Yes, supporting API level 9 and above would exclude <5% of devices as of the beginning of June. http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html#Platform

Comment: The main question is if you want the 3.2% of API 8 or not. The current default setting of Android Studio, for example, suggest to still use 8.

Comment: I agree with Warren, you are confusing Java for PC's with java for Android.  The 2 are fundamentally different.  As he said, you don't target java 1.1, 1.5,1.6 etc when running android apps.  You target API levels.

Comment: Well, we're actually using the JAVA SDK for PC to compile a .jar, which is then packaged into the APK.  So, I may have gotten them confused, but I still am talking about the Java SDK target, not the API level.  We're calling "javac.exe -target 1.1 ...".